# IE Cross Browser Button Issue

Tags: css, css-float, wrapper

http://www.pcdconsultancy.co.uk/

Im currently debugging in IE a website, and trying to establish what is causing  a button to float outside its wrapper

the code for my sidebar is :

```
<div class="homepagesidebar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="mctitlelatestnews">
                <div class="exclamationmark"></div>Latest News
            </div>
            <div class="latestpostsbox">
                <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('homepage-sidebar') ) :?><?php endif; ?>

                <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=2' ); ?>

                <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
                    <i class="sidebarbluetext"><?php the_date('jS F Y'); ?></i>
                    <?php the_content(__('(more…)')); ?>
                    <br/>
                <?php endwhile;?>

                <div class="morewrap">
                    <a href="http://pcdconsultancy.co.uk/index.php/projects/">more</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <br/>
            <div class="projectboxtitle">
                <div class="projectsicon"></div>Recent Projects</div>
                <div class="projectsbox">
                    <?php
                    if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('recentposts-sidebar') ) :
                    endif; ?>

                    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=1' ); ?>

                    <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(218,200) ); ?>

                    <?php endwhile;?>

                    <div class="projectsmorewrap"><a href="http://www.milknhny.co.uk/SofiaWork/?page_id=12">more</a></div>
                </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I dont see the DIV being open so im at a loss! Can anyone please advise?

Comment: the ul closes after the divs?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't close the projectboxtitle div anywhere.

Comment: unless im mistaken i closed it? <div class="projectboxtitle"><div class="projectsicon"></div>Recent Projects</div> ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I tried your website in both Chrome and IE and I got the same result. Which button is floating outside?